# system config dynamic row change save style

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, dynamic-rows

Using [tutorial](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/dynamic-row-system-config.html) I have managed to add dynamic rows with 2 column:

**1** - Customer Group

**2** - Price for customer

Both fields showing in system config and saving as well.

issue is when I check in database it is showing like:

{"_1611305135170_170":{"customer_group_id":"32000","price_for_customer":"23"},"_1611305140170_170":{"customer_group_id":"1","price_for_customer":"444"}}.

When I checked system configuration for **minimum allowed qty** at **Store** > **Configuration** > **Catalog** > **inventory** > **Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart**, it is saving values in  database like:

{"0":1,"3":20,"2":3}

How can I achieve same save technique ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you need to apply some json functions (get nested objects) to extract the desired values, and then you store it in your $data before saving the model.

Comment: @AbdulSamadAbbasi, could you please give some code example ?

Comment: Can you write how exactly would you like this to be saved in DB. I suppose `{"0":1,"3":20,"2":3}` is just an example?

Comment: it is used by magento when save minimum allowed qty for diff customer group.

Answer (score 1):

That's one way I'm gonna show, maybe there would be some pre-defined functions that I'm not aware of. You can search about them

```
$obj= '{"_1611305135170_170":{"customer_group_id":"32000","price_for_customer":"23"},"_1611305140170_170":{"customer_group_id":"1","price_for_customer":"444"}}';
    $obj = json_decode($obj,true);
    $newarr = [];
       foreach ($obj as $key=>$value) {
           {$temp = 0;
               foreach ($value as $nestedkey=>$nestedval)
               { 
                if($nestedkey == "customer_group_id"){
                    $temp = $nestedval;
                }else
                   $newarr[$temp] = (double)$nestedval;
               }
           }    
       }echo json_encode($newarr);
```

the `$obj` will be your `$data['field_name']` in `Save` controller before saving the model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need to change how the data is saving!